# Terraform - When creating an EBS snapshot, how to provide permission for an account number?

Tags: terraform, aws-ebs

How to add permissions to a different account when creating an EBS snapshot with terraform?

```html
resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "example_snapshot" {
  volume_id = "${aws_ebs_volume.example.id}"
  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld_snap"
  }
}
```

from console we can add the account number from here
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi7mI.png)